# Changing a reminder on a calendar event changes the event id, not reminder id

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I am trying to write some code that can tell if the reminders on an event were changed (either one added or removed) but I'm getting a weird occurrence. Instead of the reminder being removed or altered, it appears the event is being removed and re-added! Is my code incorrect? Or is this what's really occurring?

To test this, you'll need to:

1. create an event with a reminder
2. click the button after that syncs t your emulator
3. Remove the reminder on the event
4. Wait till that change syncs to your emulator and then click the button again

**JAVA CODE**

```
package com.example.remindertest;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Instances;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Reminders;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class ReminderActivity extends Activity
{
    final static public String TAG = "ReminderActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Add button
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_activity);
        Log.d(TAG, "Started");
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            Reminders.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null
        );

        String str = "";

        /*
        * Some crappy code to test this
        */
        while ( cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            int eventId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders.EVENT_ID));
            Cursor eCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                Events.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { Events._ID, Events.TITLE },
                "_id = ?", new String[] {"" + eventId}, ( String ) null);

            eCursor.moveToNext();
            String title = eCursor.getString(eCursor.getColumnIndex(Events.TITLE));

            str += eventId + " = " + title + " = " +
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders._ID)) + " = " +
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders.METHOD)) + " = " +
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders.MINUTES)) + "\n";
        }

        Log.d(TAG, str);
    }
}
```

**LAYOUT XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".ReminderActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MANIFEST XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.remindertest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
    android:name="com.example.remindertest.ReminderActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: exactly same happens on my phone...Strange.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code is correct. Exactly same happens on my 6 devices - event changes it's id (probably is recreated) when you edit it. Btw, it happens also when you change event's time, title, location or any other details - not just reminder. Funny is, that it doesn't always happen - just sometimes. But usually 2-3 edits of event are enough to simulate this behavior.

I do not quite know the reason why event's frequently changes their ids, but based on this I would say, that event's id shouldn't be used as unique identifier.